# convert byte array to pdf and bind the result to src of an iframe

Tags: c#, iframe

I am currently reading byte array from DB.I want to convert this byte array to Pdf and Want to show this converted pdf in an iframe.
How do i assign the response data to src of iframe in c# ?
Thanks.

Comment: _Did you tried anything to solve this?_ Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: yes.I have set src of iframe to an aspx page like this :   iframeDoc.Attributes.Add("src", "PdfForm.aspx"); and in this aspx page i am trying to convert byte array and  writing the response.output :   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(arrDocumentImage);
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "Inline");
                Response.Buffer = true;
                ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);  When i use this i am getting  an error as :"Form error : Not pdf Or pdf corrupted"

Answer (score 0):

Two options: [base-64 encode it as a data uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038922/setting-the-src-attribute-of-an-iframe-to-dataapplication-pdfbase64) (note not all browsers like this), or use a regular uri that refers to a route (a separate http request) that fetches the data as normal. This can be done either by deferring the conversion until the second request, or by storing the generated output somewhere temporary between the requests.